# import file (NOT: import file as f)

Tags: python, maya

So I have added my scripts path to systaphs and now when I want to use my defs or classes I do:

```
import myFile as f

print f.FILE.NAME
```

But this is making my code sometimes look more confusing and I want to get rid of the "f". I made the class FILE to use it like enum in C++, to be usefull and easy to read. How can I import myFile to use my defs of classes like:

```
import myFile

print FILE.NAME
# Error: NameError: file <maya console> line 3: name 'FILE' is not defined #
```

Comment: Did you try `from myFile import FILE` ?

Comment: On a side note it's common to use lower case for package an module names : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names

Comment: Well all my defs are in seperate file, so I guess it is a module, right? However I dont get "from myFile.f import FILE" since myFile is a module not f? At least thats how I understand modules from the help

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to names *from* a module in your import:

```
from myFile import FILE
```

Importing adds one or more names to your namespace. Using `import <module>` binds the module name, and using `as` you get to pick your own name for the module.

Using `from <module> import <object>` you get to bind any of the module attributes to a name (by default the name of the `<object>` attribute); you can still use `as` to pick a different name.

Only the names you import are available. When you use just `import myFile`, only `myFile` is set, not any of the attributes on `myFile`.

Answer (score -1):

I have just tested for you buddy.Here are the two files in the same directory:

```
 File 1#: main.py
 def hey():
     print 'Hey'
```

---

```
 File 2#: main2.py
 import main
 main.hey() 

 #or

 from main import hey
 hey()


C:\Users\Baby>python main2.py
output : Hey
```

I think it will work for you.

Comment: Ok Actually this works for defs but not for classes. This is my class:
>
class FILE:
----OLD_DIR = 0
----NEW_DIR = 1
----NAME = 2

Comment: @JozefPlata: a class is *just an object*, and so is a function. If it works for a function, it'll absolutely work for a class.

Comment: Yeah, always hate answering with code on stackoverflow, never know how to paste the code to display right and have limited time to answer... Jeeeeeeeeez. Need to do some tutorials on HOW TO THE HELL ANSER A POST on stackoverflow... sorry got a little angry here :P

Comment: @Martijn Pieters well actually somehow it does not work for classes for me :(

Comment: @JozefPlata: Both `def` and `class` create an object that is bound to the given name. To an import, there is *no difference at all* between importing either. If something is not working for you, it *can't* be the difference between a class and a function. There will be other differences between the two situations.